# can you disable auto-configuration for ActiveMQ on condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

Is there a way to disable auto-configuration for ActiveMQ if the properties for the connection factory are not specified? when I don't exclude ActiveMQ auto-configuration, Spring boot auto configures ActiveMQ with default parameters like broker-url=localhost:61616. I need to have ActiveMQ auto-configured only if the ActiveMQ properties below are specified:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://blah.com:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=password
```

Comment: You can exclude the autoconfiguration by using exclude on the ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class

Comment: You don't need to exclude anything , you provide your own connection factory . ActiveMQAutoConfiguration import class ActiveMQXAConnectionFactoryConfiguration     ( this class will Autoconfigure  only if you are not providing your own connection factory, Create your own Bean connection factory based conditional on your property